# How primitive should the alien technology be to exchange knowledge and culture?

Tags: aliens, technological-development, moons, space-travel

In almost every sci fi alien trope there will be a directive whereby one of the general order states no spacecraft may interfere with the normal development of any alien life or society and is punishable by death.

Suppose humans have developed wrap drive and discovered a hospitable moon orbiting a Jupiter-sized gas giant in a distance star system, is there any criteria for these human explorers to assess whether should they reveal their presence and study the alien lifeforms or observe from a distance?

Comment: To existing and potential down voters: why do you find the moon annoying or disturbing it is just one moon after all can't you give it a rest...

Comment: The question has **nothing** to do with moons.

Comment: @o.m. correction do you mean the question has little to do with moons since my setting is on an alien moon not planet, I am happy to refund the negative vote what says you?

Comment: The answer would be exactly the same if the setting was a planet rather than a moon. That means tagging it with moon is misleading.

Answer (score 1):

First, I want to disagree with your premise. Star Trek has the [Prime Directive](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AlienNonInterferenceClause?from=Main.PrimeDirective), the [Culture](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Literature/TheCulture) has Special Circumstances. Not "almost every" setting protects primitives.

The purpose of such a prime directive is to protect the natural development of those interdicted civilization, until they can meet the galaxy on a level playing field. So they are arguing that it is **moral** to deny them vaccination, sustainable agriculture (slash and burn is [bad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slash-and-burn)), or Seinfeld re-runs, because that's "not natural" for their stage of development.

Have pro-contact do-gooders and pro-protection do-gooders argue it out, each citing precedents how the other side screwed up.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I think the only thing we shouldn't do when it comes to an ET race is impose our government or laws on them but I think it is ok to reveal our presence to them and exchange ideas and knowledge between them regardless of how primitive they are.  I don't think the exchange of disease is much of a risk because most organisms on Earth are not able to contract human diseases and the further two species are apart the less able they are to exchange diseases and even intelligent ETs would be more distance from us biologically than we are from plants.  Without diseases simply deciding to start trading with an ET civilization would be unlikely to harm them in any way.  One thing to be careful with is that we should avoid assuming that what we know about human medicine, psychology, and health would apply to the aliens although we could use the scientific method to figure out what is healthy for that species, what kind of medicine works best for that species, how their psychology works, and what is healthy for that species.  The laws of physics on alien worlds will the same so what we know about physics as well so we could exchange knowledge of physics as well as math and chemistry with ETs.  Basically the only thing that would be crossing the line would be toppling an alien government, imposing our laws on the aliens, or imposing a human government on them but the exchange of knowledge and ideas is ok.

Comment: I believe that it is my right and duty to impose basic human rights on other *human* civilizations, if I can do so without creating more suffering than the lack of human rights would bring. *No one shall be held in slavery or servitude; slavery and the slave trade shall be prohibited in all their forms.* That's worth fighting a war. Why would it be any different for other species?